# HERE maps for JavaScript API: How to calculate route?

Tags: javascript, symfony4, here-api

I wanna implement in my project option to draw route on the map using HERE maps api, I read documentation and saw few examples and if I implement it all global and push static route to calculate distance like that:

```
    const platform = configPlatform();
    const defaultLayers = configLayers();
    var markers = [];
    var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10,
    }
    );

    var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);
    var icon  = setCustomMarker();

    const lineString = new H.geo.LineString();
    var polyline;
    var routingService = platform.getRoutingService();
    var routingParameters = {
    'mode': 'fastest;car',
    'waypoint0': 'geo!50.1120423728813,8.68340740740811',
    'waypoint1': 'geo!52.5309916298853,13.3846220493377',
    'representation': 'display'
    };

    routingService.calculateRoute(routingParameters, success => {
    console.log(success);
    });
```

It works fine, but I wanna do everything in functions (instantiate platform must be global and it's ok). First of all I wanna by navigator configure center of map (current user position) and next by event listener give user possibility to add markers to map and it all works but if I wanna next push data to routing service and calculate route between markers and whole distance I get following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: c is not a function at eval(eval at  (mapsjs-core.js:70), :64:238)

Even if I just call method routingService.calculateRoute() inside eventlistener I get the same error.It looks like something in calculateRoute function must be instantiate in time map loading because it works ok when I calculateRoute next to loading map but if I use that function I listener It doesn't work. Somebody had any idea how to make it possible to run this method in listener (instantiate globally routing service doesn't help) ??

Comment: Could you be specific about what you want? the question is too deep on what you want!

Comment: I just want call method calculateRoute() from click event listener with waypoints given by user (user click in two places and first router is calculated and if he click one more time on another place the route should be recalculate)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with little update in calculateRoute callback and all worked perfectly:

```
routingService.calculateRoute(routingParameters, success => {
    console.log(success);
});
```

If the problem persists, please attach a link to simple working example with this issue.

Recently I created simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0w3sktxp/) example for adding routing waypoints on `contextmenu` (right-click) event callback, maybe it could also help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, that's mistake in stackoverflow copy of code in real project I also had the same piece of code like you and if everything is call immediately after page load it works fine,  like I wrote before. Maybe I wrote that not so clarify as possible. The problem starts If i try call method calculateRoute from event listener. I check jsfiddle code... if that not help I wilk paste complete (not working) example in jsfiddle and paste link here.

Comment: Ok I read all your code from jsfiddle and I configure that you don't do anything special to let method calculateRoute() working inside of eventListener. And I try run your code on my local machine and it's working. So this let me think "maybe some libraries from my project is the problem" and I try run my code in empty page without any external libs like jQuery, bootstrap etc. and it's working now. Now I try configure which one lib makes problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

And I configure that the externals libs weren't problem. I could run the same code page without any custom code of twig and assets and one page deployed on lamp server works properly. Second one identical copy deployed on symfony server still had error in js console

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: c is not a function at eval(eval at (mapsjs-core.js:70),"

If I try read error after reject by console log I get:

> Error: [] 
>   https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.12.0&apikey=(my api key here)=fastest%3Bcar&waypoint0=geo!50.1120423728813%2C8.68340740740811&waypoint1=geo!52.5309916298853%2C13.3846220493377&representation=dragNDrop request failed at eval (eval at  (mapsjs-core.js:70)

When I click into link I had a lot of numbers and on the end distance so the error response looks for me like success response. That's realy odd for me. I thought symfony server cannot ingerate in js on client side. Someone had any possibilities what is wrong ??

Comment: I don't think this is server issue. Can you share link to the app with the error?

Comment: I can't share link because it is working in localhost now but I paste link to screens (maybe that helps). First image shows the same html and js code run by lamp server, second one is the same page runs on symfony server [link](https://imgur.com/a/AS3pEpA). Now I think the problem is not in server but in link 'https:// 127.0.0.1:8000/workout/add_drawed' (maybe it's problem with port or https??).

Comment: I check the same code page on another project in symfony and it has the same problem. I install CA for chrome (I thought 'Not secure' info in chrome causes problem but it's not). I looked into console log from server and when I go to this page I get following log: "2020/03/18 00:15:35 http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:51468: EOF". Maybe that is cause of this problem?? If not I had no idea why the same code working at one enviroment (LAMP) and in another didn't (Symfony server).

Comment: I see what you mean. Unfortunately I have no solution for that, but in few weeks there will be update on the API with some fixes if used together with other libraries like Angular, Ember.js, etc.. Maybe it will help with your issue too.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for help. Fortunately I had few more things to do so I let this problem open, and maybe it will be works fine after update if not I try Google maps.